# Animation in Android

Tags: android, animation

I am new to the android programming. In My app I first load splash screen and then the login page, both are separate activities. I need to give a page flip like animation to the removal of splash screen like in the iPhone. How can i implement that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here is a good tutorial](http://www.inter-fuser.com/2009/08/android-animations-3d-flip.html) on Flip 3D animation in Android.